# Convert HH:MM:SS string to number of minutes

Tags: t-sql

I have the below query.

```
select cast(dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, TimeIn, TimeOut), 0) as time(0) )
```

I get the results from two columns in the format of hrs-min-seconds.
I would like it in the format of min only. So `02:47:00` will read `167`.

Comment: what db, mysql, sql server?

Comment: hey, could you please go through your questions and award the people with the best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQL Server (works for 2005 too):

```
select Datediff(mi,convert(datetime,'00:00:00',108), convert(datetime,'02:47:00',108))
```

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server Query:

```
SELECT cast(substring('02:47:00',1,2) AS int)*60+
       cast(substring('02:47:00',4,2) AS int)+ 
       cast(substring('02:47:00',7,2) AS int)/60.0 AS minutes
```

MYSQL Query:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC('02:47:00') / 60
```

Result:

```
| MINUTES |
-----------
|     167 |
```

Comment: Works exactly how I needed it to for my call duration field.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @Time DATETIME = '01:05:00'

select ((DATEPART(HOUR, @Time)*60) + (DATEPART(MINUTE, @Time)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
datediff(minute, 0, '02:47')
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Justin's answer. This allows for situations where hours is larger than 2 digits.

```
declare @time varchar(50) = '102:47:05'

SELECT cast(right(@time,2) AS int)+
       cast(left(right(@time,5),2) AS int)*60+ 
       cast(left(@time,len(@time)-6) AS int)*3600 AS seconds,
       (cast(right(@time,2) AS int)+
       cast(left(right(@time,5),2) AS int)*60+ 
       cast(left(@time,len(@time)-6) AS int)*3600)/60.0 AS minutes
```

Result:

```
seconds     minutes
----------- ---------------------------------------
370025      6167.083333
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,CAST('00:00' AS TIME), CAST('02:47' AS TIME)) AS difference
```

Gives you:

```
| DIFFERENCE |
--------------
|        167 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you want to use DATEPART function for values with more than 24 hours, you will receive an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

You can test it with this code:

```
declare @Time DATETIME = '32:00:00'
select ((DATEPART(HOUR, @Time)*60) + (DATEPART(MINUTE, @Time)))
```

To solve this, I worked with this another approach:

```
declare @tbl table(WorkHrs VARCHAR(8))
insert into @tbl(WorkHrs) values ('02:47:00')
insert into @tbl(WorkHrs) values ('32:00:00')
-- Sum in minutes
SELECT TRY_CAST(([HOURS] * 60) + [MINUTES] + ([SECOND] / 60) AS INT) as TotalInMinutes
FROM (
SELECT 
    -- Use this aproach to get separated values 
    SUBSTRING(WorkHrs,1,CHARINDEX(':',WorkHrs)-1) AS [HOURS],
    SUBSTRING(WorkHrs,4,CHARINDEX(':',WorkHrs)-1) AS [MINUTES],
    SUBSTRING(WorkHrs,7,CHARINDEX(':',WorkHrs)-1) AS [SECOND] -- probably you can ignore this one
    FROM @tbl
)
tbl
-- Sum in seconds
    SELECT TRY_CAST(([HOURS] * 3600) + ([MINUTES] * 60) + [SECOND] AS INT) as TotalInSeconds
    FROM (
    SELECT 
    -- Use this aproach to get separated values 
    SUBSTRING(WorkHrs,1,CHARINDEX(':',WorkHrs)-1) AS [HOURS],
    SUBSTRING(WorkHrs,4,CHARINDEX(':',WorkHrs)-1) AS [MINUTES],
    SUBSTRING(WorkHrs,7,CHARINDEX(':',WorkHrs)-1) AS [SECOND]
    FROM @tbl
)
tbl
```

This code will return like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
$time = '02:47:00';

$time = explode(":",$time); 

$total = ($a[0]*60)+$a[1];

echo 'Minutes : '.$total;<br>
echo 'Seconds : '.$a[2];
```

Comment: I don't recognize this as tsql

Comment: Considering the only tag is tsql and the example query is tsql, this is completely off topic.