# To format time(0) datatype

Tags: t-sql

I have the below query.

`select cast(dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, TimeIn, TimeOut), 0) as time(0) )`

In this i get the results from two columns in the format of hrs-min-seconds. I would like it in the format of minutes only . So 01:05:00 should be retrieved as 65.
How can i rewrite the query?

Comment: Please do not ask [exactly the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746849/convert-hhmmss-string-to-number-of-minutes) twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select datediff(minute, TimeIn, TimeOut)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT datediff(minute, 0, TimeOut) - datediff(minute, 0, TimeIn)
```