# Converting an AVG from HH-MM-SS to Minutes

Tags: sql

I have a query like this:

```
with first_reply as (
select 
  t.id as ticket_id,
  tc.created,
  row_number() over(partition by tc.ticket_id order by tc.created) as rn

  from ticket t
inner join ticket_comment tc
  on t.id = tc.ticket_id
inner join user u 
  on u.id = tc.user_id
where u.role in ('employee')
order by tc.ticket_id, tc.created)

select 
   avg(far.created-t.created_at)

from ticket t
inner join first_agent_reply far
  on far.ticket_id = t.id
join ticket_tag tt
  ON tt.ticket_id = t.id

AND rn = 1
```

It gives me an avg time in the format of 22:23:56.973609

How can I convert this to showing me just total minutes? Ie: 1920 Mins

Thank you!

Comment: Tag spam does not help us help you. I've removed said tag spam, please retag the RDBMS you are *really* using, and **only** that RDBMS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746849/convert-hhmmss-string-to-number-of-minutes  1920 mins is 32hrs though?

Comment: When I `cast(interval'22:23:56.973609'hour to second  as interval minute(6))`, I get 1343.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sql server please use the below function,

```
DATEDIFF(minute, 0, CONVERT(TIME,'22:23:56.973609'))
```

Probably the last part of your code will be like this,

```
select 
DATEDIFF(minute, 0, CONVERT(TIME,avg(far.created-t.created_at)))
from ticket t
```

The answer you get here is 1343